# phpredis on fedora 12

Tags: php, redis

I am trying to install phpredis to work with my php.
But the thing is, every time I try to get it to work, my error_log sends this error:

[code]PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Redis' not found in /var/www/html/testme.php on line 5[/code]

I have downloaded the source code from http://github.com/owlient/phpredis
and then

```
phpize
./configure
make && make install
```

but still not working.

What can I do now?

Comment: Enable the module? Call dl('redis')? What does phpinfo() say?

Answer (score 5):

specifically, created a redis.ini:

```
$ cat /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/redis.ini 
;configure the redis module
extension=redis.so
```

I filed a github issue, hopefully they'll make it create the ini automatically, or at least explain in the install instructions:
https://github.com/owlient/phpredis/issues/94

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work.

I had to give the full path in php.ini, restarted httpd and voila it works :D

Comment: * this edit goes in the "Dynamic Extensions" section of the php.ini file, and the full entry is this: 'extension = redo.so'