# Having problems trying to use the phpredis class

Tags: php, redis

I have done the following instructions to install phpredis, and they have been successful:

```
phpize
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Then, I added the following line: `extension=redis.so`
to the directory: `/Applications/XAMPP/etc/php.ini`

I am using this code:

```
  $redis = new Redis(); 
  $redis->connect('localhost', 6379);
```

But, I get the following error:

```
Class 'Redis' not found in /Users/egidra/Sites/Admin/phpredis.php on line 131
```

Comment: Does it show up in phpinfo()?

Comment: Take a look at [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279047/phpredis-on-fedora-12) related to php.ini path.

Comment: He said that he had to give it the full path to redis.io. I do not know where redis.io is located, though. It's not in the phpredis folder.

Comment: I added the following line: extension=/Users/egidra/Sites/Admin/phpredis/modules/redis.so, and it didn't work.

Comment: are you running apache? I assume you restarted your server.