# using phpredis - ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

I am trying to install phpredis library for using redis in my php scripts. I folloed the instructions here https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis , ran the script for apache usage too. I added a redis.ini to `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d` in which I write `extension=redis.so`. I checked that `redis.so` is present in `/usr/lib/php5/20090626` where other libraries like `mysql.so` are also present. 
Mysql works well in php, but when I try to use php redis,

`$redis = new Redis();`

This call doesn't return, anything after this statement is never executed.

PS: I am fairly new to php, ubuntu, redis etc.

**Edit:** I had to just restart apache server. Question can be closed.

Comment: Check your phpinfo() to see if Redis module is loaded. If not please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279047/phpredis-on-fedora-12

Answer (score 0):

Two things that you can check here :

- First is your phpinfo to find out if redis extension is installed or not
- Check if there is no authentication enabled in redis.conf file.

In case authentication is enabled connect it by passing credentials.